# Socket Server and NUnit: Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, sockets, testing, nunit

I am writing a socket server and client classes, which I'm testing through NUnit.

I wrote a process, which is checking all clients, if they are still connected. For this process I created a Thread, but what I want is to run this check only like every 5 seconds. My first intension was to use `Thread.Sleep()`. When I am ending the test, I am running the Stop method on server, which interrupt all active threads, which is causing that `Thread` was interruted from a waiting state.

I find out there is alternative through the `Task.Delay().Wait()`, but this is causing the same problem.

Is there any other alternative to `Thread.Sleep`, or any other way, when I am closing server to end this thread? The thread is running while loop with condition `Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive`.

Comment: `Dictionary<connectionID, DateTime>` The date time represents when you last checked. A loop can do the checking.

Comment: Hah! This sounds like a good workaround!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61768611/c-sharp-program-processes-in-background), I found a better solution, because I want run the check only in periods of time (like 5 seconds or so), the good usage here is `System.Threading.Timer` class, which is suitable for the periodacal run of methods.